# MediaException: Cannot create DataSoruce for capture://audio on Samsung

Tags: audio, java-me, samsung-mobile, mmapi, amr

I'm writting midlet that captures audio on mobile.

```
System.getProperty("supports.audio.capture"); - returns true

Manager.getSupportedContentTypes("capture"); - returns "audio/amr"
```

My mobile is Samsung SGH-G800 and according to its spec supports JSR-135, but on that:

```
Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=audio/amr");
```

I get this exception:

```
MediaException: Cannot create DataSoruce for: capture://audio?encoding=audio/amr
```

I tried also "capture://audio", "capture://audio_video" and "capture://audio?encoding=pcm". Nothing.

Any ideas why I get this exception?

crosspost: [link](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2130379&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Player p = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=amr");
```